# How to verify HTTP/2 connection pooling/reuse in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, http, networking, http2

From WWDC videos, it is clearly mentioned if we use HTTP/2 on the server and if we are using `URLSession` the connection pooling works out of the box. How to verify this is working?

I am using `URLSessionTaskMetrics` to verify this, but when i see the metrics, it is using `networkProtocolName` is h2. so in the server HTTP/2 is already enabled, but the property `isReusedConnection` is `FALSE`

1. In HTTP/2 the connections are reused to increase the performance,
   but any idea why `isReusedConnection` is `false`?
2. Do i need to turn on any settings for connection pooling? or am I
   missing something?
3. Is there any other way to verify connection pooling in iOS?

Answer (score 2):

`isReusedConnection` can be `true` or `false` for both HTTP/1.1 of HTTP/2 protocols because it's depends on `URLSession`'s alive connections.

**HTTP/1.1**

`URLSession` creates a connection pool of 4 connections to a single domain  by default and use them to send requests e.g.:

```swift
var requestNum = 0

class Metrics : NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didFinishCollecting metrics: URLSessionTaskMetrics) {
           for metric in metrics.transactionMetrics {
                print("\(requestNum). protocol: \(metric.networkProtocolName!), reused: \(metric.isReusedConnection)")
                requestNum += 1
           }
       }
}

let metrics = Metrics()
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: metrics, delegateQueue: nil)

func makeRequests(_ http: String) {
    requestNum = 0
    for i in 0...10 {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://\(http).akamai.com/demo/tile-\(i).png")!)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
        task.resume()
    }
}

makeRequests("http1")

Outputs:

0. protocol: http/1.1, reused: false
1. protocol: http/1.1, reused: true
2. protocol: http/1.1, reused: true
3. protocol: http/1.1, reused: false
4. protocol: http/1.1, reused: false
5. protocol: http/1.1, reused: false
6. protocol: http/1.1, reused: true
7. protocol: http/1.1, reused: true
8. protocol: http/1.1, reused: true
9. protocol: http/1.1, reused: true
10. protocol: http/1.1, reused: true
```

As you can see there are 4 new connections (reused: false) are created for the session and all next requests reuse them later.

**HTTP/2**

`URLSession` works the same as for HTTP/1.1 but creates a single connection to a domain and sends all requests through it e.g.:

```swift
makeRequests("http2")

Output:

0. protocol: h2, reused: false
1. protocol: h2, reused: true
2. protocol: h2, reused: true
3. protocol: h2, reused: true
4. protocol: h2, reused: true
5. protocol: h2, reused: true
6. protocol: h2, reused: true
7. protocol: h2, reused: true
8. protocol: h2, reused: true
9. protocol: h2, reused: true
10. protocol: h2, reused: true
```

New connection was created for the first request only from above and next requests just reuse it later.

**Connection lifetime**

`URLSession` is designed for typically client applications and doesn't hold connections to a server all the time. Connections are alive about 20 secs and then the session closes them so it creates new connections each time for not frequent requests.